# Pesquisas de índices em um vetor R

Tags: array, r

No RStudio como escolher elementos de um vetor que estejam em posições pares ou ímpares?

Comment: RStudio é apenas sua IDE, você quer se referir a linguagem R?

Answer (score 5):

Você pode criar dois índices que identificam as posições pares e ímpares

```
x <- rnorn(1500)
par <- (1:length(x) %% 2) == 0 
impar <- (1:length(x) %% 2) != 0
```

depois é só chamar o vetor com esses índices

```
x[par]
x[impar]
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma é se aproveitar da **reciclagem** que acontece automaticamente no R.
Exemplo:

```
x <- 1:15
x[c(TRUE, FALSE)] # retorna os ímpares
x[c(FALSE, TRUE)] # retorna os pares
```

Lembrando que os índices começam do 1 no R.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda.